# hasClass inside directive always returning false

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got this looping 7 times on the HTML side:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in response.Fields">
    <input type="text" name="abc" ng-class="field.DataType == 'DATE' ? 'form-control datepicker' : 'form-control'" autocomplete="off" check-date />
</div>
```

And on the directive side:

```
directive('checkDate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', //attribute only
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            console.log($(elem[0]).hasClass('datepicker')); // returning false
            console.log(elem[0].hasClass('datepicker')); // also returning false
        }
    };
});
```

When I know 1 out of the 7 fields does indeed get the `.datepicker` class (I verified using the inspect tool), how can make sure my directive works and shows `true` for that one element?

### Update

I logged the element and this is what I'm getting

```
<input name="abc" ng-class="field.DataType == 'DATE' ? 'form-control datepicker' : 'form-control'" autocomplete="off" check-date="" class="ng-scope" type="text">
```

So it seems that the check if happening before the the classes are being applied. In such a case, what would be the solution?

Comment: Log the element itself and see if it actually has the class

Comment: If you wrap your `console.log()` statements inside a `$timeout()` do they properly detect the class?

Comment: @Huangism Updated question with logged content

Comment: @asprin can you check for `field.DataType` in your directive?

Comment: @Lex Yes, timeout of 2 seconds makes it work.

Comment: @Huangism `field.DataType` is working fine since I'm getting the desired result when used inside a `$timeout`

Comment: @asprin you misunderstood, I mean can you check for that in the directive instead of hasClass since that's the condition that adds the class, you might as well check for it

Comment: We can access that object inside directive's `link` function?

Comment: @asprin I don't know what your setup is but that's what I was asking you

Answer (score 2):

Your directive is initialized earlier than the ng-class is being applied. I can see two ways to solve this problem:

1. Wait for one digest cycle to make sure `ng-class` has been applied:

   ```
   // inside your directive
   $timeout(function() {
     console.log($(elem[0]).hasClass('datepicker')); // true
   });
   ```
2. Pass `field.DataType` via an additional attribute and access this value in your directive:

   ```
   HTML:
   <input ... check-date field-data-type="vm.field.DataType" />

   JS:
   directive('checkDate', function() {
     return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: {
         fieldDataType: '='
       },
       link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
         console.log(scope.fieldDataType);  // "DATE"
       }
     };
   })
   ```

   The second way is more preferrable.